# Visual FoxPro 7 Resource Recommendations

Tags: resources, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm supporting a legacy application written (poorly) in VFP 7 and was hoping that someone could point me toward any good (or just any, actually) resources for learning FoxPro.

I can understand the code I'm going through, but I'm uncomfortable with writing any at the moment and have 2 weeks to a month to get up to speed.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be more than happy to offer some mentoring and guidance to help via email if you'd like.  Additionally, what language(s) are you used to developing with.  I might be able to help jump-start you on parallels between VFP and C#.  There are a lot of parallels with basic class construction, properties, events, methods, etc...

Comment: That would be great! C# is my primary language at the moment. My e-mail is andycallebs@gmail.com. I'll delete this comment once I get your e-mail. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

The [Hacker's Guide to Visual FoxPro 7.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930919220) is an excellent language reference.

Comment: It's a fantastic guide. Searching through the github repo is a good way to find anything specific.